# why is "78.137.18" not rejected as an invalid IP address?

Tags: android, sockets, exception

I'm trying to print something when an  exception occurs in my android program, in my socket's exception block.

But, even if I give an invalid ip address, my Exception is not being called.

```
      try{
      SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("78.137.18" , 8364);
      } 
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually a valid IP address.

```
mslade@mickpc:~$ perl -nle 'use Socket; print inet_ntoa(inet_aton($_))'
78.137.18 
78.137.0.18
```

The constructor for `InetSocketAddress` will also accept hostnames.

If you want to specifically reject those addresses (but are you sure?) then you will have to write code to check the address string, maybe with a regex.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to an IP address that I'm sure is down. Still, the exception is not being called. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

`InetSocketAddress` creates an object which represents a socket address. It does resolve hostnames to IP addresses, but it does not connect nor bind to the specified address. This is why you do not get an exception. The address is syntactically correct and a connection attempt is never made, so there is no reason to throw an exception.

Comment: I tried to connect, still I wasn't getting the exception. But now, I resolved it by having a timeoutException.